# Usage of qw(:const) with use statement

Tags: perl

Sorry for a very basic question, but I'm beginner level at Perl and could not find a suitable explanation on SO (or anywhere else!) for this question. I understand I can write a few examples and try to decipher this but I can really use some knowledge from the experts.

I'm going through some code where the developer has sourced libraries using:

```
use libExample qw(:const)
```

Now from what I understand this means sourcing the constants from libExample but would really like to know how this works.

1. Why can't I simply say: `use libExample qw(const)`
   (Trying to understand relevance of `:`)
2. Is there something we can/should write in `libExample.pm` itself to make other developers utilizing this library to mention such options in place of const that is.

Thanks!

Comment: Try this: http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html

Comment: @rubikonx9: You should explain that in more detail and put it in an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
use libExample qw(:const)
```

will pick all names in `$EXPORT_TAGS{const}` anonymous array and will import them to current namespace.

Whereas

```
use libExample qw(const)
```

will pick const and will import it in current namespace.

There are also other variants:

```
[!]name         This name only
[!]:DEFAULT     All names in @EXPORT
[!]:tag         All names in $EXPORT_TAGS{tag} anonymous array
[!]/pattern/    All names in @EXPORT and @EXPORT_OK which match
```

Please go through [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) documentation for more details on the topic.

Comment: simbabque covered an example in detail which I suggest everyone should read, but accepting this as answer as this is more precise and explained to the point, which immediately cleared up the doubts that I had.

Answer (score 8):

The syntax `use Foo qw(:const)` is using the EXPORT_TAGS feature in [Exporter](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/Exporter#Specialised-Import-Lists).

When you set up your library module, you usually have a bunch of functions or class variables. Then you configure Exporter by telling it what to export by default

```
package Foo;
use Exporter;

our @EXPORT = qw( frobnicate );

sub frobnicate { ... }
```

or when they are asked for.

```
OUR @EXPORT_OK = qw( frobnicate barnicate );

sub barnicate { ... }
```

But you can also tell it to group things together, so the user of your library does not need to list all the methods. Consider this example.

```
package Foo;
use Exporter;

our @EXPORT_OK qw(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday);

sub monday { ... }
sub tuesday { ... }
sub wednesday { ... }
sub thursday { ... }
sub friday { ... }
sub saturday { ... }
sub sunday { ... }
```

Now if I wanted all the working days, I'd have to do this:

```
use Foo qw(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday);
```

That's one long line. Instead, it would be super useful if those could be grouped. Well, they can be. If you do this instead in your library:

```
package Foo;
use Exporter;

our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( 
    working_days => [ 
      qw(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday)
    ],
    weekend_days => [
      qw(saturday sunday)
    ]
);

# ...
```

We can then use it with one tag instead of five function names:

```
use Foo qw(:working_days);
```

Note that this is equivalent:

```
use Foo ':working_days';
```